# how to build tor on windows using visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, tor

I am unable to  build tor which is in C using Visual Studio C++?
Kindly give me any readme file or suggestions related to implementation in visual studio only.

I'm new to TOR

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [documentation](https://svn.torproject.org/vidalia/vidalia/trunk/INSTALL) under 'building with Windows Visual Studio', it can't be much more clear than this. Hope that helps.